# Getting undefined is not an Object ( evaluating 'this.props.url')

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to build a component in my app that will display a name with a link to website on it and seem to be getting the error `Getting undefined is not an Object ( evaluating 'this.props.url')`. I tried to fix this by adding a `.bind(this)` but it either leads to a syntax error or the same error.

Here is the code for the component

```py
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { Linking, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     sciName: {
      textAlign: "center",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      color: "black"
     }
    });

    class LinkedName extends Component<Props> {
      render() {
        const { latinName } = this.props;

        return (
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={this.goToUrl}
            hitSlop={{ top: 50, left: 50, bottom: 50, right: 50 }}
          >
            <Text style={styles.sciName}>{latinName}</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        );
     }

     goToUrl() {
       const { url } = this.props;
       Linking.canOpenURL(url)
         .then(supported => {
           if (supported) {
             Linking.openURL(url);
           } else {
             alert("cannot open this link");
         }
       });
     }
    }

    export default LinkedName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `goToUrl` method is not bound to the component's instance.

You should either bind it in the constructor of the class, or declare it as an arrow function.

```
// Arrow function declaration
goToUrl = () => {
  const { url } = this.props;
  Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
    if (supported) {
      Linking.openURL(url);
    } else {
      alert('cannot open this link');
    }
  });
};
```

Have a look at [React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) about event handling and binding.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up binding the function in a constructor.